# SQL not accepting my string as a condition in a CASE statement

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I am using SQL Server and SSMS.

I am writing a CASE expression in SQL. Here is one of the lines

```
WHEN [Group] = 'Representation Accepted' AND [Reason] = 'Reduced to Warning Notice' Area Authorised' THEN 31
```

The issue I am having here is that for the string:

```
Reduced to Warning Notice' Area Authorised
```

SQL is getting confused with the quotation mark here and believes it to be the end of the condition and completely omits " Area Authorised". I'm not sure how to solve this issue without removing the single quotation mark. Does anyone know how I cam make SQL accept the entire string with the quotation mark as a condition?.

Comment: Double the quote - `'Reduced to Warning Notice'' Area Authorised'`.

Comment: BTW, that's a `case` _expression_.

Comment: Is there a way to do it without altering the actual string itself?

Comment: You can perhaps pass the string as a parameter?

Comment: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/388759/why-should-i-tag-my-rdbms

Comment: There was a solution in the link which I think could have worked also which is to CONCAT the string using the unicode id for the single quote rather than actually typing the character.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use two times single quotation as below

```
WHEN [Group] = 'Representation Accepted' AND [Reason] = 'Reduced to Warning Notice'' Area Authorised' THEN 31
```